# Help with "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do' "

Tags: ssh, bash, script, terminal, cluster

Background: Yes, I'm a noob.  I've been learning Debian Linux the last several months.

Here's the situation:  I have 10 Raspberry Pi's (3B+) with hostname rpi-100 to rpi-109. I am trying to automate repetitive tasks. I've generated an ssh-key & copied it to all the pi's. Here are some of the tasks I'm able to do, but only from the command line (cli).

```
for node in {101..109}; do echo "rpi-$node:" && sudo ssh pi@rpi-$node 'sudo apt-get update'; done
for node in {101..109}; do echo "rpi-$node:" && sudo ssh pi@rpi-$node 'sudo apt-get upgrade -y'; done
for node in {101..109}; do echo "rpi-$node:" && sudo ssh pi@rpi-$node 'sudo apt-get install boinc-client -y'; done
for node in {101..109}; do echo "rpi-$node:" && sudo ssh pi@rpi-$node 'sudo systemctl reboot'; done
```

Question: How can I put these tasks in a bash script? I keep getting "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
".

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: Those statements are fine. What's happening in your script _before_ the first `for` loop?

Comment: I could try to work out what you ACTUALLY want to do (which you haven't explained). What you appear to be trying is sending dozens of commands over ssh to a remote shell. If you wanted to do this you need to start new shells. No one would do this.

Comment: This is a general Linux question - not Pi specific

Comment: Login fixed.  to: glen jackman... first line of script is: "#!/usr/bin/bash"    As I said in my question; I am trying to send commands like "apt update" to 9 raspberry pi 3b+'s in a script rather than CLI.  The reason for the sudo before each ssh command is each pi will use the rsa-key and NOT ask user to input password.  This is the best I can figure-out from man pages.

Comment: I know what i'm doing is beyond beginner linux and not quite in the realm of pentesters.  If anyone knows a good site for learning these topics, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of review-type comments (not an answer to your question).

- you shouldn't need to `sudo ssh`.
- you can execute several commands on the remote system in one ssh session.
- put them into the background so they can operate in parallel:

  ```bash
  for node in {101..109}; do
      echo "rpi-$node:" 
      ssh pi@rpi-$node '
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get upgrade -y
          sudo apt-get install boinc-client -y
          sudo systemctl reboot
      ' &
  done
  wait   # wait for the background jobs to complete.
  ```

Comment: Wow! Thanks.  a much more elegant syntax of my script.  I use sudo to make each pi use the rsa-key from the master node (rpi-100). Otherwise they stop & wait for a user to input password for each pi node.